# Get Text and Positions from a Java jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea

I want to get the individual texts and their positions as they 
 are entered in an editable jTextArea.

for example ,the following string:  "this is java"

should provide the following:

**word      position**
  this        p1
   is         p2
  java        p3

any suggestion on how to achieve this.
 kind regards.

Comment: You can just get the text from the text area and use `indexOf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setText("this is java");
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(textArea.getText());
int position = 1;
while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    System.out.println("Position" + position + ":" + stringTokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Output is

```
Position1:this
Position1:is
Position1:java
```

However you wish to know current CaretPosition then you can do `textArea.getCaretPosition();`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] words = myTextArea.getText().split("\\s+");
for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("word position " + words[i] + " p" + (i+1));
}
```